# warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int'; take the address with &

Tags: c, debugging

I have this code and I'm trying to debug it now and I get this error:

```
warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
      'int *' with an expression of type 'int'; take the address with &
      [-Wint-conversion]
    int * b = a[1];
```

The code I'm debugging is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
  
int main() {
    int ii;
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int * b = a[1];

    for (ii=0;ii<6;ii++) {
        printf("%d ",*(b+ii));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int * b` is a pointer.  `a[1]` is an `int`.  Why try assigning an `int` to a pointer?

Comment: Array indexes start at 0. And, you need the _address_ of `a`. So, change `int *b = a[1];` into `int *b = &a[0];` And, you can use the "array form" of dereference [it's cleaner], so: `*(b + ii)` --> `b[ii]`

Comment: The error message tells you how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

The array name variable `a` acts as a pointer i.e. the starting address for the **consecutive** memory block storing the values.

Thus, you can access the addresses in the loop either by incrementing the pointer i.e.

```
    int *b=a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        printf("%p\n",b++);
    }
```

or through the pointer of the value at that index

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        printf("%p\n", &a[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
int *b;
```

b is a pointer, a[1] is an integer...

Try:

```
int *b;
*b=a[1];
```

That will take us to the funny part. You have no memory for it!

Other way:

```
int *b=(a+1);
```

Yet another:

```
int *b=&a[1];
```

Comment: You can clearly see (on line `printf("%d ",*(b+ii));`) that, s/he is gonna use `b` as a pointer. So, `*b=a[1];` will not work for this purpose. It's better to use `b = a` or `b = &a[0]`.

Comment: That is why I wrote other options. I don't have to assume what is the purpose of the variable.

Comment: You do **not** need to assume. It's not an assumption. It is crystal clear that s/he is going to use `b` as a pointer on `printf` line. Besides this fact; you can not create a pointer and assign a value to it without creating a valid memory address that it's pointing to. A plain line `int *b;` will create a pointer but it's not pointing to any memory space; so, you can not assign a value using de-reference operator (`*b = a[1]` or even `*b = 2` will definitely fail to compile). You'd better revise *pointers* chapter.

Comment: If you read my answer, you will find "That will take us to the funny part. You have no memory for it!" I think it takes into consideration all the possibilities. As the OP did not ask for anything I just expose all the possible changes. I don't need to revise pointers and I don't know why that attitude towards me.

Comment: Please do not take this personal. Down votes do not address you or anybody else but the printed text. The last code line (`int *b = &a[1];`) is closest to the true answer that would work, among other lines you offer and it would be correct if it had been printed as `int *b = &a[0];`.